# C++ Como pegar a string do método get de uma classe x e concatenar com uma string de classe y?

Tags: c++, string, classes, get, falha-de-segmentação

Estou programando um código em qt(C++) e preciso de pegar valores da classe cliente na classe menu(que não herda de cliente) e concatenar numa string para fazer impressão na tela. segue o código:

```
cliente* cl = new cliente();
```

Posteriormente no código setei valores para o cliente e entao chegou na parte que não está funcionando:

```
string g = "Dados do cliente: \n   Nome: " + cl->getNome() + "\n   Email: " + cl->getEmail() + "    Telefone: " + cl->getTelefone() + "\n   Endereço: " + cl->getEndereco() + "\n   Carro : " + cl->getCarro() + ", " + cl->getAnoCarro() + "    Placa: " + cl->getPlaca() + "\n";
```

O erro é segmentation fault. A maneira na qual está meus getters é essa para todos(são todos string):

```
const string &cliente::getPlaca() const {return placa;}
```

Alguém tem idéia de como consertar?

Comment: Todos os métodos são strings ? Incluindo o `getTelefone` ? Tem como colocar um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) do problema ?

Comment: Sim, todos são string, converti todos para string para salvar.

Comment: Um exemplo esse: tenho a classe cliente, ai na classe menu importei cliente.h, e criei um new cliente(). ai em dado momento setei valores para esse meu cliente, e esbarrei nesse problema: nao consigo formatar uma string usando os dados do cliente, da falha de segmentacao.

Comment: Mas dá erro a compilar ? Ou só da erro a correr ?

Comment: So a correr mesmo, compila normal

Comment: Tem como colocar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável do problema ?